# Passing multiple, single or none parameters through URL cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

so I have the following controller function for adding events:

```
public function add($id = null, $year = null, $month = null, $day = null, $service_id = null, $project_id = null){
...
}
```

What I need to do in some cases is to pass only the id and service_id or project_id and to skip the year, month and day. I have tried to pass parameters as empty strings or nulls as following, but none of it seemed to work.

```
echo $this->Html->link('Add event', array(
    'controller' => 'events',
    'action' => 'add',
25, null, null, null, 3, 54
))
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It would be easy if you use named parameters instead of passed.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#named-parameters

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest solution would probably to use query parameters. (I tend to not use named parameters anymore as CakePHP will drop them soon or later)

View:

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('add event'), array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'add', '?' => array('id' => 123, 'service_id' => 345, ...)));
```

Controller:

```
public function add(){
    $id         = isset($this->request->query['id'])         ? $this->request->query['id']         : null;
    $year       = isset($this->request->query['year'])       ? $this->request->query['year']       : null;
    $service_id = isset($this->request->query['service_id']) ? $this->request->query['service_id'] : null;
    ...

}
```

This way it would be easy to have only some of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing them as `/var/var/var`, just use URL variables:

```
www.whatever.com?id=123&month=4
```

Then access them:

```
$id = $this->request->query['id'];
$month= $this->request->query['month'];
... etc
```

Feel free to check if they're set or not empty first...etc, but - seems to fit a lot better for what you're going for.