# Cake PHP route with multiple parameter

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.0

```
   public function brand($brand=null,$model=null,$city=null){
       print_r($this->request->getParam('pass')); exit;
   }
```

if only passed parameter brand then url should be like this
mydomain.com/used-{brand}-cars

if passed parameter brand and city then url should be like this
mydomain.com/used-{brand}-cars-in-{city}

if passed parameter brand and model then url should be like this
mydomain.com/used-{brand}-{model}

if passed parameter brand,model and city then url should be like this
mydomain.com/used-{brand}-{model}-in-{city}

Please suggest me how to achieve these type of urls . Can we obtain with one action or every url will have different action. Please explain all possibility. I am totally confused.

Comment: Did you check this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469587/passing-multiple-single-or-none-parameters-through-url-cakephp

Comment: Yes I have checked but i know how to pass multiple parameter.But i want to know that how to write route for the same like which i have mentioned in question?